# Returning rows selected in with statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql statement looking something like this

```
WITH [ResultPage] AS (
SELECT sub.id as id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TAG].[Name] ASC, [TAG].[ID] ASC) As [RowID], [sub].[hasPending]
    FROM
    (SELECT t.[ID], p.[TagID],(CASE WHEN p.[TagID] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [hasPending]
    FROM [Tag] AS t
     full outer Join [TagPending] AS p On t.[ID] = p.[TagID]
     GROUP BY t.[ID],p.[TagID]
    ) AS [sub]
     inner Join [Tag] On [Tag].[ID] = sub.[ID]
)

SELECT [ResultPage].[RowID], [Tag].[ID] As [Tag^ID], [Tag].[Name] As [Tag^Name]
 FROM [ResultPage] 
INNER JOIN [Tag] ON ([Tag].[ID] = [ResultPage].[TagID]) 
INNER JOIN  [TagPending] ON ([TagPending].[TagID] = [KbResultPage].[TagID]) 
WHERE (([ResultPage].[RowID] BETWEEN 1 AND 50)
)
ORDER BY [ResultPage].[RowID] ASC
```

As can be seen, the select max returns 50 rows at a time, however I need to know the total number of rows found in the WITH statement. I could run it again with just a count, however it could be nice if there were a way to get both in one go.

Comment: You would have to include the column with each row returned (same value in each row). To me doesn't sound like a good approach.

Comment: If you really want to.. you could add an additional join INNER JOIN(SELECT Count(*) as MAXCount from ResultPage] ) COUNT ON 1=1 and Add the column to your select list. Again as said earlier... not a good approach

Comment: Another way is to change the with statement section into a temporary table statement, then do a SELECT @@ROWCOUNT before the actual select, thereby having 2 return sets, one for max rows and one for data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the COUNT(*) OVER() in the WITH statement

```
WITH [ResultPage] AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS totalRows,  
sub.id as id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TAG].[Name] ASC, [TAG].[ID] ASC) As         [RowID], [sub].[hasPending] 
   FROM 
  (SELECT t.[ID], p.[TagID],(CASE WHEN p.[TagID] is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  [hasPending]
   FROM [Tag] AS t
   full outer Join [TagPending] AS p On t.[ID] = p.[TagID]
   GROUP BY t.[ID],p.[TagID]
   ) AS [sub]
inner Join [Tag] On [Tag].[ID] = sub.[ID]
)

SELECT
 [ResultPage].totalRows,
 [ResultPage].[RowID], [Tag].[ID] As [Tag^ID], [Tag].[Name] As [Tag^Name]
FROM [ResultPage] 
INNER JOIN [Tag] ON ([Tag].[ID] = [ResultPage].[TagID]) 
INNER JOIN  [TagPending] ON ([TagPending].[TagID] = [KbResultPage].[TagID]) 
WHERE ([ResultPage].[RowID] BETWEEN 1 AND 50)
ORDER BY [ResultPage].[RowID] ASC
```